# Proving $a = b = c$ under certain conditions

Tags: inequality

For all real a, b, c, prove a = b = c if $$\frac{a^2+b^2+c^2}{3} = (\frac{a+b+c}{3})^2 $$

The first idea that came to mind would be to prove this inequality by contradiction. However, I am unsure about how to go about it. Would using the AM-GM inequality be useful? This is what it could possibly be simplified to make things easier:

$$ 2(a^2 + b^2 + c^2) = 2(ab + ac + bc) $$

Any help would be extremely appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$2(a^2+b^2+c^2-ab-bc-ca)=(a-b)^2+(b-c)^2+(c-a)^2\ge0$, with equality holds if and only if $a=b=c$.

Answer (score 3):

By Cauchy inequality we have $$(1+1+1)(a^2+b^2+c^2)\geq (a+b+c)^2$$ with eqaulity iff $a:b:c=1:1:1$ i.e. if $a=b=c$.

We have more: $$(1+1+...+1)(a_1^2+a_2^2+...+a_n^2)\geq (a_1+a_2+...+a_n)^2$$

with equality iff $a_1=...=a_n$.

Answer (score 2):

Write 
$$ 2(a^2 + b^2 + c^2) = 2(ab + ac + bc) $$
As 
$$ (a^2 + b^2 - 2ab) + (c^2 + b^2 - 2cb)+ (a^2 + c^2 - 2ac) = 0$$
Now since $ (a^2 + b^2 - 2ab) = (a-b)^2 $
The expression becomes
$$(a-b)^2 + (a-c)^2 + (c-b)^2 =0 $$ 
Which is only true if $$ a = b = c $$

Answer (score 0):

$$a^2-a(b+c)+b^2+c^2-bc=0$$ is a quadratic equation in $a$

As $a$ is real, the discriminant must be $\ge0$

i.e., $$(b+c)^2-4(b^2+c^2-bc)=-3(b-c)^2\ge0$$  which is possible only if $b-c=0$

$\implies a=\dfrac{b+c}2=\dfrac{c+c}2$